# How to use bash script with \n (new line) in makefile

Tags: sed, makefile, compilation

I have written a code with several options that can be activated in a `.h` file (define.h). I want the compiled version of my code make a file (e.g. define.dat) and writes the defined parts in it at the time of execution (to keep track of what we used or not).

So far, I managed to make a `sed` script to convert the file in a format I want to present.

```
echo '"' `cat define.h | grep '#def' | grep -v '//#def' | sed 's;/.*$$;;' | sed 's/$$/ \\\n/'` '"' > define.dat
```

And I learned that with

```
const char *s = {
#include "define.dat"
};
```

I can implement it in the code at the time of compile.

The first script is working fine in Bash environment (please notice double `$` is not required), however, when I put it in makefile (where I need double `$`), `\n` is interpreted as newline instead. Consequently, the compiler gives error.

Any suggestion or new method?

Comment: MCVE please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and more info (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `cat | grep | grep | sed | sed` is one of the 7 deadly sins.

Answer (score 0):

I found a small work around, however, not satisfied with it. I used `-` as delimiter

```
echo '"' `cat define.h | grep '#def' | grep -v '//#def' | sed 's;/.*$$;;' | sed 's/$$/ - /'` '"' > define.dat
```

and instead of

```
const char *s = {
  #include "define.dat"
};
```

I used

```
char s[] = {
#include "define.dat"
};

for (i=0 ; s[i] ; i++)
  if (s[i] == '-')
    s[i] = '\n';

if ((fout = fopen("define.dat","w")) == NULL)
  fprintf(stderr,"Error in creating define.dat\n");
else
{
  fprintf(fout,s);
  fclose(fout);
}
```

to replace all the `-` with `\n`.